# Can I use the stovetop while a dough is leavening in the oven?

Tags: bread, dough, oven, leavening

I usually use my (turned off) oven as a safe place for leavening doughs for hours.
I always get amazing results and never had any issue with that.

But... what if I need to use the stovetop?
Will the oven heat up and ruin my dough? Or the temperature change will be imperceptible, having no effect on the dough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a thermometer?  Place it in your oven.  Check temp.  Turn on your burners/use stove for a bit.  Check temp.  You will then know for sure.

Comment: That's the only way to know. I've had stoves where you really couldn't, stoves where this would be a good way to warm the oven (like leaving the light on),and some where you wouldn't notice any warmth at all. Newer ovens tend to be much better insulated,and that keeps heat out as well as in

Comment: When I wrote this question, I already had the dough in the oven, so it was impossible to check with the thermometer. 
I was hoping to find an universal answer, but looks that really it depends by each oven. 
Thank you. Your answer is correct and helpful, even if is not the answer I was expecting :)